# How to use Maven Shade plugin?

Tags: java, maven, neo4j, maven-shade-plugin

In my project I want to avoid version conflict of `neo4j lucene indexer` (which uses lucene version - 3.6.2) and `apache lucene` (lucene version - 5.3.0). For this I want to use Maven shade plugin. Actually, I added plugin to my projects 'pom.xml' file but problem wasn't solved. I get exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer: method <init>()V not found
    at com.sessa.col.spr.act.dictionary.DictionaryConfiguration.writerConfiguration(DictionaryConfiguration.java:124)
    at com.sessa.col.spr.act.process_flow.Flow.startProcess(Flow.java:59)
    at com.sessa.col.spr.act.process_flow.FlowHandler.main(FlowHandler.java:17)
```

It seems that it is caused by version conflict again. I guess, I don't use Maven Shade plugin in a correct way. How should it be used?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sessa.col.spr.act</groupId>
<artifactId>Color-Spreading-Activation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Color-Spreading-Activation</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <neo4j-version>2.2.5</neo4j-version>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparsity</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkseejava</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.apache.lucene</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded_lucene_3_6_2.org.apache.lucene</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j-repo</id>
        <name>Neo4j Repository</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this project to eclipse -> https://github.com/lagodiuk/neo4j-uber-jar.
2. Use mvn-install and create ~SNAPSHOT.jar
3. Add that .jar to your project (which has conflict)
4. Remove neo4j maven dependency from that project.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that maven-shade will help you here. You basically want to have multiple versions of the same jar - lucene 3.6.2 and 5.x.y used at the same time.

The only solution I'm aware of here is using classloader separation.

However it might be worth refactoring the architecture to prevent that problem by separating Neo4j and your code into separate JVMs.